# Is there a way to prevent keyboard from hiding when textfield disappears?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard-events

I am trying to implement an audio recording button in a chat interface, similar to what you can find in Whatsapp or Telegram for example: when you press the microphone button, it replaces the text field by a recording UI, and when you release the microphone button, it sends the recording. So in my input bar, I have a Row, containing an Expanded that wraps the TextField when I'm not recording, and the recording UI when I am recording. Something like this:

```
Row(children: [
    ...
    Expanded(
      child: _recordingAudio
          ? const Text('recording')
          : TextField(
               controller: _textController,
               keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
               maxLines: 5,
               minLines: 1,
            ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(Icons.mic_none), 
      onTapDown: (details) => setState(() { _recordingAudio = true; }),
      onTapUp: (details) => setState(() { _recordingAudio = false; }),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image: Before I tap down on the mic button]

And the general functionality works, except that when the textfield has focus and the keyboard is visible, if I tap down on the mic button to set `_recordingAudio` to true, the `TextField` disappears, so it loses focus, so the keyboard disappears, and the mic button slides down from under the user's finger.

[image: After I have tapped down on the mic button]

Is there any way to prevent the keyboard from hiding in that situation?